# JavaFX ProgressBar problems

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, progress-bar

I am having a problem with synchronizing my progress bar and my web engine load worker. I have looked everywhere, but alas no solution. My problem: When my web engine fails to load an invalid URL the progress bar still hangs. What I need: I want my progress bar to be setVisible(false) or .toBack() when the URL cannot load. Thank you SO!

Answer (score 0):

> I want my progress bar to be setVisible(false) or .toBack() when the
>   URL cannot load.

You pretty much answered your own question , you get an exception when you fail to load URL , so in catch block `setVisible(false) or .toBack()` on your progressBar .

**If you want more detailed answer please provide a code , edit your question, i will edit my answer**

Comment: Haha, I was just about to edit this postxD. I ended up changing my conditional statements around by adding an else if(newState == State.RUNNING) { pb.toFront(); pb.setVisible(true); } and it worked perfectly to siphon out the non loading URLS. But, I ran into one more problem with my browser. I noticed that the progressbar never comes up for the first URL I enter, but it works great afterwards. Any solution to this? Thank you!